# Translate angularjs breadcrumb in the stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, ncybreadcrumb

I want to translate my breadcrumb elements like this:

url: moduls/1/question

breadcrumb: Moduls -> Modul 1 -> Question

The problem is the "Modul 1" part. My translation for this is

```
"MODUL_TAG": "Modul {{short}}"
```

breadcrumbtemplate:

```
<ol class="navbar-nav list-unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="step in steps" ng-class="{active: $last}" ng-switch="$last || !!step.abstract">
        <a ng-switch-when="false" href="{{step.ncyBreadcrumbLink}}" title="{{ step.ncyBreadcrumbLabel }}">{{step.ncyBreadcrumbLabel | translate:translationData }}</a>
        <span ng-switch-when="true">{{step.ncyBreadcrumbLabel | translate:translationData }}</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

State:

```
.state('modul.show', {
    url: "/{short}",
    templateUrl: "partials/modul/show.html",
    controller: "ModulShowCtrl",
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: "MODUL_TAG"
    }
})
```

The problem is that i don't know where I have to place the translate-data.

I tried it with the ModulShowCtrl but without success.

```
$scope.$parent.translationData = {
    short: $stateParams.modulId
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should translate your breadcrumb in your state definition, like this :

```
.state('modul.show', {
    url: "/{short}",
    templateUrl: "partials/modul/show.html",
    controller: "ModulShowCtrl",
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: '{{ "MODUL_TAG" | translate }}'
    }
})
```